# PowerShell GUI - Function within a Form not working

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface

currently i am working on an little PowerShell GUI Porject.

I have a Form within this Form there's a Button to call another Form that provides an Listbox with some items in it.
So far so good - i'm getting the results as expected.

Now i mark one of the items - click on OK - then it should do something.
And here is my Problem, it does nothing :D No Error, no warning, just nothing.
If i test with write-host "$($listBox.SelectedItem)" - i get the selected Item as i expect it.
But if you want to use it with get-adfsrelyingpartytrust -Name $listBox.SelectedItem - nothing happens.
If i execute the function without the rest (so that only the listbox appears) everything works as intended O_o.

Code:

```
function single_rpt{    $RPTForm                        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
                        $RPTForm.ClientSize             = '400,200'
                        $RPTForm.Text                   = "Choose"
                        $RPTForm.BackColor              = "#b2b2b2"
                        $RPTForm.AutoSize               = $false
                        $RPTForm.StartPosition          = 'CenterScreen'
                        $RPTForm.ControlBox             = $true


                        $rptButton                             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
                        $rptButton.BackColor                   = "#ffffff"
                        $rptButton.Text                        = "OK"
                        $rptButton.Width                       = 90
                        $rptButton.Height                      = 30
                        $rptButton.Location                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,125)
                        $rptButton.Font                        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
                        $rptButton.ForeColor                   = "#000000"
                        $rptButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor     = $true
                        $rptButton.DialogResult                = 1
                        
                                                
                        # Test List Box
                        $listBox                        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
                        $listBox.Location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,50)
                        $listBox.Size                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,200)
                        $listBox.Height                 = 80
                                                
                        $RPTForm.Controls.AddRange(@($listBox,$rptButton))
                        
                        $listboxArray = @()
                        $ADFS_RPTS = Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust
                        Foreach($rpt in $ADFS_RPTS)
                        {
    
                           #$Object = Add-Member -TypeName NoteProperty -Name Service -Value $service.Name
                           $listboxArray += $rpt.Name
                        }

                        $listBox.Items.AddRange($listboxArray)
                        [void]$RPTForm.ShowDialog()

                                                          
                        if($RPTForm.DialogResult -eq "OK")
                        {
                                    
                        Get-AdfsReylingPartyTrus -Name $listBox.SelectedItem
                                    
                        }

                        
                    }


# Init PowerShell Gui

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


# Create Form with size, title and background color, etc.

$TESTForm                        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$TESTForm.ClientSize             = '250,300'
$TESTForm.Text                   = "TEST"
$TESTForm.BackColor              = "#ffffff"
$TESTForm.AutoSize               = $false
$TESTForm.StartPosition          = 'CenterScreen'
$TESTForm.ControlBox             = $true

$RPTSingle                             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$RPTSingle.BackColor                   = "#ffffff"
$RPTSingle.Text                        = "RPTSingle"
$RPTSingle.Width                       = 90
$RPTSingle.Height                      = 30
$RPTSingle.Location                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,125)
$RPTSingle.Font                        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$RPTSingle.ForeColor                   = "#000000"
$RPTSingle.UseVisualStyleBackColor     = $true

$RPTSingle.Add_Click({single_rpt})


# Add a Cancel Button

$CancelButton                             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.BackColor                   = "#ffffff"
$CancelButton.Text                        = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Width                       = 90
$CancelButton.Height                      = 30
$CancelButton.Location                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,250)
$CancelButton.Font                        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$CancelButton.ForeColor                   = "#000000"
$CancelButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor     = $true
$CancelButton.DialogResult                = 2


$TESTForm.Controls.AddRange(@($RPTSingle,$CancelButton))
# Display the form

[void]$TESTForm.ShowDialog()


#------------------------------------#
```

Comment: Typo: `Get-AdfsReylingPartyTrus` is missing the final `t`. Should be `Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust`

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", what are you *expecting* to happen? Your code calls ```Get-AdfsReylingPartyTrust``` inside ```single_rpt``` but doesn't do anything with the result. It'll get written to the output stream of the function, but the event handler set up by ```$RPTSingle.Add_Click({single_rpt}``` will just swallow it.

Comment: Kudos to mclayton! That was what i was missing - i expected that the Information of the get- cmdlet. gets shown in the current Powershell- Host.